# Develop ASP.NET Core application in Windows and Mac

Tags: c#, windows, macos, asp.net-core, cross-platform

.NET Core is cross-platform in that you can develop and run an application on your desired platform (Mac, Linux, or Windows).  However, I can't find any information on cross-platform **development** of an application, in particular, of an ASP.NET Core application.

We are building a new website and we need to be able to have some users work on an ASP.NET Core application on Windows and some on Mac. (There is currently no need to support development on Linux.)  On the Windows side, we would ideally like to work in VS 2015 (Community).

Is this possible?  If so, are there any required or recommended steps to follow or workarounds to help make the process smoother?  Are there any limitations to this approach?

Answer (score 2):

The official documentation has everything you need to get started https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet

Update: For Visual Studio instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/

Comment: So if I follow the instructions on that page, I'll be able to open the project in *Windows* (instructions are for Mac) and build, debug, and run the site locally?  Will I be able to open it in VS 2015 Community?

Comment: Updated my answer to include Visual Studio